# Matlab Readtable Invalid parameter name: Range

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read column C from an Excel CSV file (file is too large to load entire thing). I am trying the following code:

```
filename='AS-1704-CT-Data-(Jan4---Jan-7)_1.csv';
T=readtable(filename, 'Delimiter', ',', 'Range', 'C:C')
```

The error I get says Error in (line 2), Invalid parameter name: Range.

According to the Matlab doc for readtable, Range is a valid parameter. The Name is 'Range' and the Value is 'C:C' (I've also tried 'C2:C8' while troubleshooting).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The answer is in the first link that Google gives by putting your question title in its search engine

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB interprets your file as text, and according to [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#namevaluepairs)

> When reading:
>
> Text files, only these parameter names apply: FileType, ReadVariableNames, ReadRowNames, TreatAsEmpty, DatetimeType, Delimiter, HeaderLines, Format, EmptyValue, MultipleDelimsAsOne, CollectOutput, CommentStyle, ExpChars, EndOfLine, DateLocale, and Encoding.

So Range is not a valid parameter name for text files.
You could try saving your file as an excel workbook (.xls) and reading from that.